# Handling back button on Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I'm developing an **Adobe Air 2.6** app for android tablets (using **ActionScript 3.0**).

I want to know how can I handle user back key press.

I read somewhere there is a specific **Adobe Air SDK** for **Android**, but I read it on a forum from 2010.

Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //TODO handle back key press
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}//onKeyDown
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And menu and home buttons?

Comment: Just change the constant you are comparing. Find constants here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: All of the keyevent codes can be found at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: So you can do multiple if checks to see what the keyevent is, including the back button, home button, menu button, etc.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm using ActionScript 3.0 not Java (or maybe I haven't understood your answer).